# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Tags: vue.js

I am completely lost on this one, spent a good 5 hours on it, cannot find a solution.

I have an API call that commit an action on catch error. The action then mutate a state which is the error message from the catch error as below:

**action**

```
retrieveToken(context, credentials) {
    axiosOne.post('/login', {
    username: credentials.username,
    password: credentials.password,
    })
        .then(response => {

        })
        .catch(error => {
                const errorMessages = error.response.data.errors;
                context.commit('apiErrorMessage', {errorMessages});  <-----
        });
},
```

**mutation**

```
apiErrorMessage(state, payload) {
    state.apiErrorMessage = payload.errorMessages;
    console.log(payload.errorMessages);
},
```

state

```
state: {
    apiErrorMessage: {}
},
```

It looks like the state of the object has some kind of a delay and is still undefined by the time the v-if tries to access it, causing the below error:

```
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"`
```

What is the best way to use v-if when the object is still undefined?

```
    <transition name="slide-fade">
        <div v-if="apiErrorMessage">
//also tried this  <div v-if="Object.keys(apiErrorMessage).length > 0">
        <b-alert v-for="(value, index) in apiErrorMessage" variant="warning" :key="index">{{ value[0] }}</b-alert>
        </div>
    </transition>

    <script>
        import {
            mapState
        } from 'vuex';

        export default {
            data() {
                return {

                }
            },
            computed: mapState([
                'apiErrorMessage',
            ])
        }
    </script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you put `<pre>{{apiErrorMessage}}</pre>` in your code instead of the `<b-alert>...` line and show what the result is? I'm thinking you may have something like `[null]`, which would explain the problem you're seeing

Comment: I worked it out today, the problem was between the object was coming from an Axios promise, it was not available on template render, so what I did was v-if with the property {{ apiErrorMessage }} , put the (value, index) in apiErrorMessage in a DIV and the second {{ apiErrorMessage }} on its own in the alert. This way the render does not affect {{ apiErrorMessage }} if v-if apiErrorMessage is false.